# Executing foreach based on the size of the collection

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Is there a way to execute a query, only when there is at least two elements in the collection. 
In my current situation I match nodes based on their properties and then I put them in to collection, afterwards I would like to execute a foreach statement when the size of the collection is greater than two.

This is the fragment of my query that I would like to execute when the size of the collection is greater than two elements

```
WITH COLLECT(items) AS itemsCol
FOREACH(i in RANGE(0, 1)|
  FOREACH(newItem in [productsCol[0]] | 
    FOREACH(oldItem in [productsCol[1]] | 
      CREATE UNIQUE (oldItem)-[:SEEN]->(newItem))))
```

Comment: Keep an eye out for the next release of APOC Procedures in the next couple weeks, there should be a new procedure for conditionally executing cypher code like an if/else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
WITH
  COLLECT(items) AS itemsCol,
  (CASE WHEN COUNT(items) >= 2 THEN RANGE(0, 1) ELSE NULL END) AS todo
FOREACH(i in todo |
  FOREACH(newItem in [productsCol[0]] | 
    FOREACH(oldItem in [productsCol[1]] | 
      CREATE UNIQUE (oldItem)-[:SEEN]->(newItem))))
```

`FOREACH` does nothing if the collection being iterated over is `NULL`.

Answer (score 0):

[APOC Procedures](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/) just updated with support for conditional cypher execution. You'll need version 3.1.3.7 or greater (if using Neo4j 3.1.x), or version 3.2.0.3 or greater (if using Neo4j 3.2.x).

You can use `apoc.do.when()`, since this is a query that writes to the db.

Something like:

```
...
WITH COLLECT(items) AS itemsCol
CALL apoc.do.when(size(itemsCol) >= 2, '
 FOREACH(i in RANGE(0, 1)|
  FOREACH(newItem in [productsCol[0]] | 
    FOREACH(oldItem in [productsCol[1]] | 
      CREATE UNIQUE (oldItem)-[:SEEN]->(newItem))))',
      '', {productsCol:productsCol}) YIELD value
...
```

In this case you don't need an else cypher block, so we can leave that out, though you'll need to pass in your parameters for use within the if query block.